# How to connect a mobile app to a smart meter

Tags: android, energy, meter

I am working on a app that keeps track of how much electricity and gas your house uses, how many km your car travels, and all the things that cause greenhouse gases.

I am almost finished doing the part for the car, but I have a problem with the part of how much electricity and gas your house uses. I have an idea but I don't know if it will work and how to do it. For it to work you should have a smart meter and somehow the app will connect to the smart meter and the smart meter should send the data to the app, but can this be done? If not, is there any other way that an app could keep track of how much energy and gas you use without having to fill it in manually? Because honestly I don't think anyone will do that.

Comment: THis isn't really an answerable question as-is.  It will all depend on the type of smartmeter and what APIs that model has available.  There isn't going to be a generic way to work across all meters.  So you'll have to lower your scope to a specific meter and then there may (or may not) be an answer.

Comment: for electricity you could look into https://github.com/ligi/plughub / https://github.com/ligi/MeterEdison and use some edimax - for gas I have no clue - this stuff is way to explosive for me ;-)